# Combining PySpark and DBSCAN with pandas_udf

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, scikit-learn

I was reading the documentation on pandas_udf: 
[Grouped Map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html#grouped-map)

And I am curious how to add sklearn DBSCAN to it, for example I have a dataset:

```
data = [(1, 11.6133, 48.1075),
         (1, 11.6142, 48.1066),
         (1, 11.6108, 48.1061),
         (1, 11.6207, 48.1192),
         (1, 11.6221, 48.1223),
         (1, 11.5969, 48.1276),
         (2, 11.5995, 48.1258),
         (2, 11.6127, 48.1066),
         (2, 11.6430, 48.1275),
         (2, 11.6368, 48.1278),
         (2, 11.5930, 48.1156)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "X", "Y"])
```

And I would like to groupby `id` and do the DBSCAN clustering on each `id` seperately.

```
@pandas_udf("id long, X double, Y double", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def dbscan_udf(...):
    # pdf is a pandas.DataFrame
    v = ...
    return ...

df.groupby("id").apply(dbscan_udf).show()
```

The output I am looking for is the original dataset with `cluster` column, which shows points close to each other with the same`id`.

Thank you for help!

Comment: Sklearn's `DBSCAN` is in-memory algo. The only way you can use it is to unload your data to RAM and process there.

Comment: So I want to spread each id to separate worker on cluster (like on databricks) and do the computing, I'm stuck on the code to implement this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've managed to do this by my own:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, DoubleType, StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
import pandas as pd

data = [(1, 11.6133, 48.1075),
         (1, 11.6142, 48.1066),
         (1, 11.6108, 48.1061),
         (1, 11.6207, 48.1192),
         (1, 11.6221, 48.1223),
         (1, 11.5969, 48.1276),
         (2, 11.5995, 48.1258),
         (2, 11.6127, 48.1066),
         (2, 11.6430, 48.1275),
         (2, 11.6368, 48.1278),
         (2, 11.5930, 48.1156)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "X", "Y"])

output_schema = StructType(
            [
                StructField('id', IntegerType()),
                StructField('X', DoubleType()),
                StructField('Y', DoubleType()),
                StructField('cluster', IntegerType())
             ]
    )

@pandas_udf(output_schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def dbscan_pandas_udf(data):
    data["cluster"] = DBSCAN(eps=5, min_samples=3).fit_predict(data[["X", "Y"]])
    result = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["id", "X", "Y", "cluster"])
    return result

df.groupby("id").apply(dbscan_pandas_udf).show()
```

Hope it can help someone in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have a question. I want to identify low density areas for location in my dataset, so I need to apply the algorithm on the whole dataframe, not on groups. Is it possible?

Comment: I think that then you only can use Pandas without PySpark nad udf's.

Comment: I just realized this code can be used. If I use groupBy( ) with an empty argument, the function can be applied to the whole dataset. Maybe it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's done like this.

```
# Sum
df.groupBy('id').sum().show()
```

Or, if your version of Spark is old, try this.

```
(df
    .groupBy("id")
    .agg(func.col("id"), func.sum("order_item"))
    .show())
```

See the link below for some info related to DBSCAN.

https://github.com/alitouka/spark_dbscan

Comment: Thank you for help, but it is not the case, I will try to do it tomorrow!

Comment: @ASH I also found PySpark implementation in this [github](https://github.com/SalilJain/pyspark_dbscan) May I ask you kindly to check this [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JU3eeQ09pxqE8TTzeO3MGT7X3bs38WzC?usp=sharing) to why i couldn't run DBSCAN and for quick debugging?