# Prevent Spark Out of Memory when applying Pandas UDF

Tags: python, pyspark

I am running spark version :3.1.3 on YARN cluster 2 nodes each 15 GB. I am trying to run  DBSCAN on spark based on this answer :
1)https://stackoverflow.com/a/60153719/13378785

spark_dbscan takes a dataframe which contains the features and a partition based on which some sub-groups have been created and sklearn DBSCAN will be applied later on locally .
Run_dbscan is the implementation of DBSCAN from sklearn (which the only difference i consider noise as 0 instead of -1).
As an output i just get a dataframe with some local labels for each group (which later on with another process are merged).

An example of the input and output is shown below:

```py
def create_scheme(dimensions):
    schema = StructType()
    for i in range(0, dimensions):
        schema.add(str(i), FloatType())
    schema.add('index', IntegerType())
    schema.add('partitions', IntegerType())
    schema.add('cluster', IntegerType())
    return schema

def Run_dbscan(df , eps=0.2, min_samples=45, colums=None, dim=2):
    db = DBSCAN(eps=eps, min_samples=min_samples).fit(df[colums[:dim]])
    df['cluster'] = db.labels_
    df['cluster'] = df['cluster'] + 1
    return df

def spark_dbscan(train_d_path, spark, esp=0.3, min_pts=3, dim=2, part=8,roungd=0):
    def dbscan(data): 
        return Run_dbscan(data=data, eps=esp, colums=col_d, min_samples=min_pts, dim=dim)
    #partition_df = has been created earlier and is the one displayed below as Input
    col_d = partition_df.columns
    partition_df = partition_df.repartition(X) #X integer [2~200] 
    df = partition_df.groupby("partitions").applyInPandas(dbscan, schema=create_scheme(dim))
    df = df.select([c for c in df.columns if c in ['cluster', 'index', 'partitions']])    
    #write.csv will either throw OOM or task will fail in YARN 
    df.write.csv('apath', header='true')
    return df 


Input :
+-----------+------------+-----+----------+
|          0|           1|index|partitions|
+-----------+------------+-----+----------+
|0.009805393|    -1.15588|    0|       400|
| -0.3587753|  -0.8127602|    1|       400|
| -0.3587753|  -0.8127602|    1|       600|
| 0.39499614|  0.57317185|    2|       500|
| 0.39499614|  0.57317185|    2|       800|
|-0.11886594|  -1.3287356|    3|       400|
|0.045839764|   -1.333411|    4|       400|
|  -1.406546|  0.75050515|    5|       200|
|  -1.406546|  0.75050515|    5|       300|
|  1.3432932|  -1.1720116|    6|       700|
| 0.23757286|  0.89215803|    7|       800|
| -1.0563164|   1.4410132|    8|       200|
| -0.3718215| -0.49574503|    9|       600|
|  0.7345064|  -1.3823572|   10|       700|
|  1.5790144| -0.79659116|   11|       100|
|  1.5790144| -0.79659116|   11|       700|
|-0.04173269|   1.3471143|   12|       800|
| -1.4477109|   0.5785008|   13|       200|
| -1.4477109|   0.5785008|   13|       300|
| 0.59039986|-0.057216637|   14|       500|
+-----------+------------+-----+----------+
Output:
+-----+----------+-------+
|index|partitions|cluster|
+-----+----------+-------+
|98663|       300|      2|
|80841|       300|      1|
|62544|       300|      1|
| 2977|       300|      1|
|23948|       300|      1|
|44470|       300|      1|
|84420|       300|      1|
|30907|       300|      1|
|93084|       300|      1|
|58671|       300|      1|
|58051|       300|      1|
|46485|       300|      2|
|29175|       300|      1|
|41179|       300|      1|
|95224|       300|      1|
|56119|       300|      1|
|22074|       300|      1|
|88336|       300|      1|
|16965|       300|      1|
|35793|       300|      0|
+-----+----------+-------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

For small datasets this works fine (less than 1 million rows) however for larger dataset if i run it locally it will always end up with either Heap error or OOM due to the memory which is required for the DBSCAN. SKlearn dbscan is memory based so i am expecting all the data to moved to the memory
however i expected with this implementation to be able to "split" the original dataset into smaller chuncks and prevent these errors .

So my question is how to overcome this, so  basically a trade off memory for speed
I have tried the following:
1)Increasing the number of partitions which lowers the number of data/rows grouped together thus spark would slower calculate the labels.
2)Increase the number of the dataframe partitions/shuffle (X value) .
Neither of those solutions could prevent the issue i mentioned from happening.

The only method which i haven't tried but might could work  is a filter like approach where i would create N dataframe (#N the number of partitions/sub-groups) and run DBSCAN to each of the with a for loop and then joining them together  but i couldn't find any post supporting such solution.

```py
d = {}
num_p = [1,2,3,4] #consider list with the partitionsnumber 1,2,3,4etc
for ie in num_p:
  d[ie] = df.filter((f.col("partitions")==ie)
  pandas_df = d[ie].toPandas()
  #apply dbscan
  #drop features and convert back to spark dataframe with scheme
merge all spark dataframe into one with union and move to global merging.
```